# Php script doesn't capture input fields

Tags: php

Hoping someone can guide me as to why my php script doesn't capture my input fields? Snippets and **relevant** Php bits of my code are below. All other aspects of this code which I use in other forms works well. Note, the current naming protocols are used in my javascript to tally totals which also works very well. Somehow maybe the Php script doesn't like my naming protocols??

Html code;

```
 <TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT TYPE=Hidden NAME=Product_1_value    VALUE="10.00">10.00</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=CENTER><SELECT NAME=Product_1_qty  onChange=FormatFields()><option      value=0>0<option value=1>1<option value=2>2<option value=3>3<option value=4>4<option value=5>5</SELECT></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT TYPE=Text   NAME=Product_1_subtotal VALUE="0.00"    SIZE=8 ></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT TYPE=Hidden NAME=Product_1     VALUE="0,0"    SIZE=10></TD>
```

Php code;

```
if(!isset($_POST['Product_1_qty']) && $_POST['Product_1_qty'] !=""||

        !isset($_POST['Product_1_subtotal']) && $_POST['Product_1_subtotal'] !=""||


        $product1 = $_POST['Product_1_qty'];

        $email_message .= "...xxxx...: ".clean_string($product1)."\n";
```

Comment: I started to format your code for you, but stopped because it's not actually syntactically correct. You are missing closing `if` code, and your HTML code looks like its from the mid 90s

Comment: Try changing the action= attribute of your form to http://webdev.spsu.edu/formtest.php and see what happens.  That will tell you whether the problem is on the sending or receiving side.  Also, the W3C validator is your friend: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lowercase letters for attributes and wrap them in double quotes. This will make your HTML syntactically correct.

Change to this:

```
<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="Product_1_value" value="10.00" />10.00</td>
<td align="center">
<select name="Product_1_qty"  onChange="FormatFields()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text"  name="Product_1_subtotal" value="0.00" size="8" /></td>
<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="Product_1" value="0,0" size="10" /></td>
```

You need to close your `if` statement. Also, you had a `||` at the end which is not needed.

Try this:

```
if((!isset($_POST['Product_1_qty']) && $_POST['Product_1_qty'] !="") || (!isset($_POST['Product_1_subtotal']) && $_POST['Product_1_subtotal'] !="")) {
        $product1 = $_POST['Product_1_qty'];
        $email_message .= "...xxxx...: ".clean_string($product1)."\n";
}
```

**Couple of other things:** You can close your `input` tag with having a `/` from the closing bracket. See above `HTML` for more details.

Also, you had some extra spacing in your `HTML` between attributes. Please remove them to make your code look cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Start by cleaning your HTML markup properly.

Keep your `input` elements lowercase and ensure attributes are wrapped in `"`'s.

```
<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="Product_1_value"    value="10.00">10.00</TD>
....etc
```

Once that's done, check to ensure that your variables are actually being posted to your php script.

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

<sup>*Are the fields that you expect to be there, actually there?*</sup>

If they are, clean up your `if` block.

```
if (!isset($_POST['Product_1_qty']) && $_POST['Product_1_qty'] != "" || !isset($_POST['Product_1_subtotal']) && $_POST['Product_1_subtotal'] != "") {
    // assign variables here...
}
```

<sup>*You have a trailing `||`(or) which will cause issues for you so it was removed and your `if` block was closed properly.*</sup>

---

Alternatively, you could use `empty()` to ensure the value does not `= ""`. Which makes your `if` block look similar to this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['Product_1_qty']) && !empty($_POST['Product_1_qty']) || !isset($_POST['Product_1_subtotal']) && !empty($_POST['Product_1_subtotal'])) {
    // assign variables here...
}
```